# CSS relative urls do not work when bundling in visual studio

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

In a css file i have this:

```
.social-icons li .facebook {
  background: url(../img/social/facebook.png) no-repeat;
}
```

The img directory is indeed in "../" compared to the css file.

Everything works ok if i include the css with normal markup in my `_Layout.cshtml`.

But if i use bundling:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/core-styles").Include(
        "~/assets/global/frontend/css/components.css"));
```

it breaks all images.

**Is there any way to use bundling AND have correct images without of course touching the components.css?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CssRewriteUrlTransform` when including the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/core-styles")
    .Include("~/assets/global/frontend/css/components.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

That class rewrites the URLs in the file to be absolute and it will fix your problem.